# Passing function as argument in Scala/Figaro

Tags: scala, figaro-lang

Im trying to learn Figaro and since it is implemented in Scala I run into some Scala specific issues. For example in the code below the `Importance.probability` takes two arguments, the first one is the distribution and the second one is a predicate. But when I try to run this code I get the following error:

> Missing argument for greaterThan50

which makes sense since it actually takes one argument.

Since Scala is a functional language I guess there is some smart standard way of sending functions as arguments that I have missed? I have tried to use `_` to make it partially applied but that is not working.

```
import com.cra.figaro.library.atomic.continuous.Uniform
import com.cra.figaro.algorithm.sampling.Importance

def greaterThan50(d: Double) = d > 50 
val temperatur = Uniform(10,70) 
Importance.probability(temperatur, greaterThan50)
```

Comment: `Importance.probability(temperatur, greaterThan50 _)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in Scala you can pass a [function value](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#function-value), like `greaterThan50` where a function is expected.

In this case in the `probability` method, which is defined as

```
def probability[T](target: Element[T], predicate: T => Boolean): Double
```

the second argument is a function, but why compiler does not accept when you pass `greaterThan50` which is actually a function value?

It's because there is another overloaded method in `Importance` which is defined as below:

```
def probability[T](target: Element[T], value: T): Double
```

So when we call

```
Importance.probability(temperatur, greaterThan50)
```

compiler actually picks up the seconds overloaded method. That's why it tries its best to apply the `greaterThan50` method, on some value, in order to get some result in return which can be used as second argument which is of type `T`.

In this case for disambiguation you need to [partially apply the function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#partially-applied-function):

```
Importance.probability(temperatur, greaterThan50 _)
```

which disambiguates the situation because now the type of `greaterThan50 _` is `Double => Boolean` which is an exact match for first overloaded function.

### An experiment to prove

For making sure that this approach works in non-overloaded methods, you can simply try to define the following function in your context (in an `object` for example):

```
def probability[T](target: Element[T], predicate: T => Boolean): Double = 10
```

and call it with

```
probability(temperatur, greaterThan50)   // Note that this function is defined by you
```

you'll see that there is no compile error as compiler expects a function and you are giving it a function value.

### Other options

Of course you can pass a [function literal](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#function-literal) to `probability`:

```
Importance.probability[Double](temperatur, (x: Double) => x > 50)
```

or you can define `greaterThan50` like this:

```
def greaterThan50 = (d: Double) =>  d > 50
```

which will be of type `(Double) => Boolean` which is again an exact match.

### Disclaimer

Used `figaro` version `2.4.0.0` with Scala version `2.11.2`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because you're calling a different method called `probability` than the one you think you're calling.

You're calling the companion object's `probability` method which has this signature:

```
def probability[T](target: Element[T], value: T, numSamples: Int = 10000): Double
```

You probably want something like this:

```
import com.cra.figaro.library.atomic.continuous.Uniform
import com.cra.figaro.algorithm.sampling.Importance

def greaterThan50(d: Double) = d > 50 
val temperatur = Uniform(10,70)
val alg = Importance(myNumSamples = 100, temperatur)
alg.start()
alg.probability(temperatur, greaterThan50 _)
```

Consider looking at the [Hello World](http://p2t2.cra.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Figaro-Tutorial.pdf) tutorial which uses `Importance`.